# How can I make the text color on my ubuntu theme work with different background colors?

Tags: unity, nautilus, themes, colors

I'm running 14.04 and I figured out how to edit theme colors recently so I changed some colors in the Ambiance gtk-main.css file.

I have the nautilus bg color set to dark grey and I want the text to be white. My problem is that when text is set to white, it also effects firefox text color which results in me not being able to see what I'm typing there (white text on white backgrounds). The same thing happens when I try to rename a folder or file in nautilus.

How can I keep the text color for labels in nautilus white while having other text (like in firefox and renaming files) stay black? (The line I edited to change text color is @define-color text_color under default color scheme in the gtk file). Thanks.

*EDIT: I just solved this by making the fg color black and keeping the text color white (can be done in the same file).

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it as solution. This will be useful for other viewers and close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I made the fg color black and kept text white. This still is not a perfect solution in firefox (there are still pages with color issues), but it solves this specific issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)